# Is there an SF story on the theme of language that does NOT use the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis?

Tags: history-of, languages, plot-device

There are numerous SF stories based on language but I have never heard of one that doesn't focus on the idea that language shapes thought. For example, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256359/are-there-reliable-sources-for-the-influence-of-babel-17-on-other-sf-using-stron) is a previous question that lists a few noteworthy stories in that vein.

In my opinion, it's pretty clear as to why: it's by far the most flexible and obvious language-related plot device that comes to mind, and it's genuinely difficult to think of alternatives, at least in the SF genre. I know of authors that experiment with language itself, but they tend to operate outside of the SF genre and don't usually use language as an actual device in a traditional plot.

Comment: You added the [history-of] tag, which suggests you're looking for the earliest example of such a story, but the title of your question suggests you're interested in any examples anyone can find. Which is it? Because if you're just looking for examples in general (rather than the earliest one specifically), that'd make this what we refer to as a 'list question,' and we tend to close those, as we prefer questions that can't have two or more answers which are different but equally valid.

Comment: I see what you mean. My goal was to find if there was at least one such story, and that other user found one so I am satisfied. Perhaps a way to rephrase my question would be to ask how to use language as a theme in SF without sapir-whorfing.

Comment: @Qwokker Have you read the SFE article on linguistics in science fiction? https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/linguistics

Comment: Thanks @user14111 I had never heard of this website before and it is a goldmine.

Comment: I nominate Janet Kagan's *Hellspark* which (iirc) is more about the relations between language, gesture, proxemics and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, there are several.**

While many SF stories about language use the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis as a starting point, like Chiang's *Stories of Your Life* and Delany's **Babel-17**, there are other ways to use language in an SF story.

Three examples are: ["We Have Always Spoken Panglish"](https://www.sfwa.org/members/elgin/Story-Panglish.html) by Suzette Haden Elgin, which is about cultural exploitation, not Sapir-Whorf

> "You're going to make noises at me about my obligation to science, the
> importance of adding to knowledge, all that blather," she said. "If
> the information is all locked away, nothing is added to science or to
> knowledge. And I am very old, Dr. Miche, but I am not foolish; I know
> what would happen. The day would come when someone at your USCOL would
> say 'The old lady has been dead a hundred years now, it's time to make
> the information known.' Either that would happen — and then the
> Hisheffans would have our last and only treasure — or there'd be no
> point at all in telling."

A second is Piper's Omnilingual, which discusses a way for two completely different cultures to find common referent with which translation can be accomplished.

A third is the one suggested by @user14111 - Sheckley's "Shall We Have a Little Talk" which uses an alien species with a ridiculously fast-evolving language for humorous purposes.

Comment: Probably not the earliest either, but decades earlier than that 2004 story, Robert Sheckley's 1965 story [Shall We Have a Little Talk?"](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v24n01_1965-10/page/n171/mode/2up) is also about language and does not involve the Sapir–Whorf hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you, this is quite helpful. A way to rephrase my question to be more stack exchangey would have been to ask how to include language as a theme without Sapir-Whorf, and these examples show multiple ways.